# sLDA. How much values response variable may have?

Tags: lda, topic-modeling

I try to understand in general how sLDA works. In contrast to LDA, it has 'a response variable associated with each document'. Is each document labeled just by one topic in training set or it might be labeled by multiple topics?

If it must use just one topic as label for one document, is there another LDA model which takes as input several labels for each document in training set?
If sLDA might use more then one topic as label, is there any implementation (in Python, R, C/C++, Matlab) for sLDA with multi-labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sLDA has a response variable that is a label, but that really has nothing to do *directly* with the topics.  The topics are still inferred exactly as they are with regular LDA, using probability calculations to build up N topics.  Each document ends up with a vector of length N indicating how strongly it "contains" each topic.  In sLDA it goes one step further - where it also in the model internally correlates the response label with the topics, to be able to predict what the response label should be for a never before seen document based upon its topic vector.